# How to parse ruby BigDecimal inspect?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

In the following code:

```
x = BigDecimal(10)
s = x.inspect # "#<BigDecimal:6fe4790,'0.1E2',9(36)>"
```

Is there a way to parse `s` and get the original value ? The reason is that  I have some text files with BigDecimal written in them using inspect, and I need to parse these values.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? The integer `10`?

Comment: I have some text files with BigDecimal written in them using inspect, and I need to parse these values

Comment: instead of parsing why cant you directly use `.to_s` and get rest info parsing `.inspect`. In my understanding its much cleaner.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to parse an `inspect` output. [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is a debugging tool, used to provide a usable view into an object. You should use `to_s` or format the data if you need output for production, and the various Integer, Fixnum or [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) methods if you need to manipulate the value or access its internals. If the files contain inspect output then their generating code should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"#<BigDecimal:6fe4790,'0.1E2',9(36)>"[/(?<=').+(?=')/]
# => "0.1E2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You `.to_s` to get the value in string. `.inspect` will print the object

```
x = BigDecimal(10)
x.to_s
# => "0.1E2"
```

Comment: Yes I know, however for some reason I have some text files with BigDecimal written in then using inspect, and I need to parse these values.

Comment: any example for that?

Comment: @shivam: it's not that hard to imagine something like a console log where someone just `.inspect`ed every variable

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [BigDecimal#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-inspect) is incomplete. Consider the following:

```
require 'bigdecimal`

BigDecimal.new("1.2345").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a110298,'0.12345E1',18(18)>" 
...
BigDecimal.new("1.234567890").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a16ab58,'0.123456789E1',18(27)>" 
BigDecimal.new("1.2345678901").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a14a6a0,'0.1234567890 1E1',27(27)>" 
BigDecimal.new("1.23456789012").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a1393a0,'0.1234567890 12E1',27(27)>" 
BigDecimal.new("1.234567890123").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a123780,'0.1234567890 123E1',27(27)>"
```

It can be seen from the source code for `inspect` that, if there are more than 10 significant digits, each 10 characters are separate by a space (for readability, presumably):

```
BigDecimal.new("123.456789012345678901234567").inspect
  #=> "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a0ac8b0,'0.1234567890 1234567890 1234567E3',36(36)>"
```

I suggest retrieving the string representation of the `BigDecimal` value as follows:

```
str = "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a14a6a0,'0.1234567890 1E1',27(27)>" 
str.delete(' ').split(?')[1]
  #=> "0.12345678901E1"
```

We are not finished. We must still convert the string we extract to a numerical object. We cannot use [BigDecimal#to_f](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_f), however, if the value is large in absolute value:

```
"1.23456789012345678".to_f
  #=> 1.2345678901234567
```

The safest course of action is to return a `BigDecimal` object, using the method [BigDecimal::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new), which takes two arguments:

- the value to be converted to a `BigDecimal` object, which can be an Integer, Float, Rational, BigDecimal, or String. If a String, which is what we will supply, "spaces are ignored and unrecognized characters terminate the value" (similar to `"123.4cat".to_f #=> 123.4`).
- the number of significant digits. If omitted or zero, the number of significant digits is determined from the value. I will omit this argument. (For example, `BigDecimal.new("0.1234E2").precs #=> [18, 18]`, where the array contains the current and maximum numbers of significant digits.

Note the second argument is required if the first is a Float or Rational, else it is optional.

We therefore can write:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def convert(str)
  BigDecimal.new(str.delete(' ').split(?')[1])
end

convert "#<BigDecimal:7facd39d7ee8,'0.1234E4',9(18)>"
  #=> #<BigDecimal:7facd39c7de0,'0.1234E4',9(18)> 
convert "#<BigDecimal:7facd39b7be8,'0.1234E2',18(18)>"
  #=> #<BigDecimal:7facd39ae610,'0.1234E2',18(18)> 
convert "#<BigDecimal:7facd3990638,'0.1234E0',9(18)>"
  #=> #<BigDecimal:7facd3980aa8,'0.1234E0',9(18)> 
convert "#<BigDecimal:7facd3970e28,'0.1234E-2',9(18)>"
  #=> #<BigDecimal:7facd39625d0,'0.1234E-2',9(18)> 
v = convert "#<BigDecimal:7fb06a123780,'0.1234567890 123E1',27(27)>"
  #=> #<BigDecimal:7fb069851d78,'0.1234567890 123E1',27(27)>
```

An easy way to see if the `BigDecimal` object can be converted to a float without loss of accuracy is:

```
def convert_bd_to_float(bd)
  f = bd.to_f
  (bd==BigDecimal.new(f.to_s)) ? f : nil
end

convert_bd_to_float BigDecimal.new('1234567890123456')
  #=> 1.234567890123456e+15 
convert_bd_to_float BigDecimal.new('12345678901234567')
  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Ruby you are using, so I checked [some MRI source code for BigDecimal](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c):

```
2000 /* Returns debugging information about the value as a string of comma-separated
2001  * values in angle brackets with a leading #:
2002  *
2003  * BigDecimal.new("1234.5678").inspect ->
2004  * "#<BigDecimal:b7ea1130,'0.12345678E4',8(12)>"
2005  *
2006  * The first part is the address, the second is the value as a string, and
2007  * the final part ss(mm) is the current number of significant digits and the
2008  * maximum number of significant digits, respectively.
2009  */
2010 static VALUE
2011 BigDecimal_inspect(VALUE self)
2012 {
2013     ENTER(5);
2014     Real *vp;
2015     volatile VALUE obj;
2016     size_t nc;
2017     char *psz, *tmp;
2018 
2019     GUARD_OBJ(vp, GetVpValue(self, 1));
2020     nc = VpNumOfChars(vp, "E");
2021     nc += (nc + 9) / 10;
2022 
2023     obj = rb_str_new(0, nc+256);
2024     psz = RSTRING_PTR(obj);
2025     sprintf(psz, "#<BigDecimal:%"PRIxVALUE",'", self);
2026     tmp = psz + strlen(psz);
2027     VpToString(vp, tmp, 10, 0);
2028     tmp += strlen(tmp);
2029     sprintf(tmp, "',%"PRIuSIZE"(%"PRIuSIZE")>", VpPrec(vp)*VpBaseFig(), VpMaxPrec(vp)*VpBaseFig());
2030     rb_str_resize(obj, strlen(psz));
2031     return obj;
2032 }
2033
```

So, what you want seems to be the second part of the inspect-string, `0.1E2` in your case, equal to `10`. The comment above is quite clear, this should be the full numeric value of the object. Simple regex will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
 "#<BigDecimal:95915c4,'0.1E2',9(27)>".split(",")[1].tr! "'", ''
=> "0.1E2"
```